# Translating MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing

Apologies, I'm aware there are a lot of questions like this but I can't seem to work out for the life of me why I'm not getting the same results.

Below is the MATLAB script as taken from [here](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Overlap_Add_Decomposition.html)

```
M = 33;          % window length
R = (M-1)/2;     % hop size
N = 3*M;         % overlap-add span
w = hamming(M);  % window
z = zeros(N,1);  
% plot(z,'-k');  
hold on;  
s = z;
for so=0:R:N-M
  ndx = so+1:so+M;        % current window location
  s(ndx) = s(ndx) + w;    % window overlap-add
  wzp = z; 
  wzp(ndx) = w;           % for plot only
  plot(wzp,'--ok');       % plot just this window
end
plot(s,'ok');  hold off;  % plot window overlap-add
```

This gives me the below plot

[image: MATLAB plot]

This is the python code I've written based on the MATLAB code.

```
M = 33        # window length
R = (M-1)/2     # hop size
N = 3*M         # overlap-add span
w = signal.windows.hamming(M)  # window
w = np.expand_dims(w, axis = 1)
z = np.zeros((N,1)) 
plt.plot(z,'-k')  
  
s = z
for so in np.arange(0,N-M+1,R):
    s[int(so):int(so+M)] = np.add(s[int(so):int(so+M)],w )   # window overlap-add
    wzp = z
    wzp[int(so):int(so+M)] = w # for plot only
    plt.plot(wzp,'--ob')       # plot just this window

plt.plot(s,'or')    # plot window overlap-add
```

Which gives me the below image

[image: Python plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer.  Matlib uses values and Python uses references for value names.  The offending code for you is the innocuous looking line

`s = z`

In Python, that makes s a reference to z and not a copy of zeros.  So when you also go

`wzp = z`

It all goes FUBAR.

Simple solution break the relation between `s` and `z`, by setting

`s=np.zeros((N,1))`

Also, I don't think you need to make all the arrays 2D.  I simplified the code to just 1D

```
import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


M = 33        # window length
R = (M-1)/2     # hop size
N = 3*M         # overlap-add span
w = scipy.signal.windows.hamming(M)  # window
#w = np.expand_dims(w, axis = 1)
z = np.zeros(N)
plt.plot(z,'-k')

s = np.zeros(N)
for so in np.arange(0,N-M+1,R):
    s[int(so):int(so+M)] +=w   # window overlap-add
    wzp = np.zeros(N)
    wzp[int(so):int(so+M)] = w # for plot only
    plt.plot(wzp,'--ob')       # plot just this window

plt.plot(s,'or')    # plot window overlap-add
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! I did upvote the answer as useful, but I don't have enough reputation for it to show the change. This works almost perfectly but I'm still getting the weird discontinuities for the data plotted in red. Also I didn't realise MATLAB and python references values/variable names differently so that's for that :-)

Comment: There should be a hollow check mark to the side that allows you to "pick" the best answer.

What discontinuities are you seeing?  You know that the colors are switched from the Matlab plot.  red <--> blue.  To fix change ```.plot(...ob)```  <--> ```or``` in both ```.plot``` statements

Comment: I'm seeing the same discontinuities as in my original plot indicated by the red -o the rest of the plot looks okay though and matches the matlab plot

Comment: Um. I didn't think the zero plot was important, but to fix, you have the same error.  ```wzp =z```.  I edited it above to ...```=np.zeros(N)```.
If this helped please accept the solution (check mark)